# Will this Rocket hit ground in same time for both cases or any diffeence (see fig)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rocket-science

Only Gravitation force exist.
Rocket dropped from height $h$ on ground.
Without firing rocket can hit ground in $t$ second.Rocket has enough fuel for journey of $T$ time.
Rocket does not have any kind of wings, so can't create upper lift force in presence of any fluid.

So will this rocket hit ground in same time ($t$) irrespective of that it was not fired or fired during journey?

Consider g=GM/r^2 (for any planet like earth)

[image]

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10773/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153026/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic: I didn't read all the links within those questions, but those possible duplicates talk about unpowered bullets.  That's a different situation for the reason given in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

it'll hit the ground at the same time, the vertical acceleration is independent from the horizontal movement. (because it's a free fall it doesn't depend on the mass too, if you think that firing can change mass )

Comment: Does this assume a flat earth (i.e. the distance traveled horizontally is much smaller than the curvature)?

Comment: yes, looking at your picture the ground is flat.

Comment: (It's a simplification you set in your assumptions, if you want to ask about orbital or sub-orbital trajectories you can make another question.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a flat ground, no atmosphere, and no "tumbling" of the rocket under power, they would both hit the ground at the same time.

**With an atmosphere** and a rocket that has a cylindrical shape as you have drawn, the rockets will tend to rotate to keep their noses pointed toward their direction of travel.  As a consequence, the thrust vector of the powered rocket will not stay parallel to the ground and **the powered rocket will hit the ground first.**

Things could get more complicated if the center of mass of the powered rocket is far enough toward the rear.  Then the rocket would have a tendency to fall rear-first due atmospheric drag.