# Why does a bullet shot from a gun take so long to fall?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, projectile

If you just drop a standard lead bullet, it falls in like 1 second. If you shoot it from a gun, why does it take so long to fall down? Doesn't gravity pull on it the same speed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does gravity affect bullets?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10773/)

Comment: This is explored here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10773/how-does-gravity-affect-bullets , and the answer is given vacuum the time taken is the same. (Note that if the bullet could reach escape velocity it would never hit the ground !)

Comment: This is just an illusion. It takes the same time for the bullet to fall as compared to a ball dropped from the same height.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you shoot it horizontally and the ground is flat, it doesn't: it takes the same amount of time to hit the ground as a bullet that's dropped from your hand.

This is easily seen from elementary kinematics, $x = ut + 1/2 at^2$. $u$ is zero for both cases, and $a = g$, so the time taken is the same.

Comment: It is unusual to use a coordinate system in which the positive $x$-axis is “down”, *especially* when you have mentioned shooting the bullet horizontally. Normally the horizontal would be $x$ and the negative $y$ or $z$ axis would point down.

Comment: It's just the formula that I internalized - some people use $s$ to represent the displacement, for example, and would write that equation with $s$ instead of $x$.